# Importing bookmarks from Firefox to Chrome

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, google-chrome

How can I import Firefox bookmarks (and saved passwords, if possible) into Google Chrome in Ubuntu, without reinstalling Chrome and waiting for the import dialog to pop up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import data under the options dialog in the personal stuff tab

Answer (score 0):

Try [xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/).

> Intall Xmarks on each computer you
>   use, and it seamlessly integrates with
>   your web browser and keeps your
>   **bookmarks** safely backed up and in
>   sync.

Edit: Xmarks' home pags doesn't state support for Chrome, but [wikipedia- Xmarks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmarks) does. I'll return after research, and appreciate clarifying comments!

Edit: [Beta version from Google](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ajpgkpeckebdhofmmjfgcjjiiejpodla)